# Django Requiring Optional Form Field Error

Tags: django, image, model, upload

To new readers: Neverwalkaloner's solution solved the initial error but the photo upload is still required and making required false in forms.py gives me a MultiValueDictKeyError. Any help on making it optional would be greatly appreciated.

---

I have a model and form to upload either a picture and text, or just text. My intention, actually was to make it a choice between an image, text or both and any help with that would be appreciated, but I digress. Uploading only works when an image is included, if it is just text, I get the error:

```
The view lesyeux.views.posts didn't return an HttpResponse object. It 
returned None instead.The view lesyeux
```

My model is:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploaded_images', blank=True, 
    null=True)
    text_post = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

My form is:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.FileField(label='Select an image file', 
    help_text='Please select a photo to upload')
    text_post = forms.CharField(help_text="Please enter some text.") 
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('image', 'text_post',)
        exclude = ('author',)
```

My view is:

```
def posts(request, id=None):
    neighborhood = get_object_or_404(Neighborhood, id=id)
    form = PostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = Post(image = request.FILES['image'])
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post = post.save()
            next = request.POST.get('next', '/')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        return render(request, 'posts.html', context = {'form':form, 
        'posts':posts, 'neighborhood':neighborhood})
```

and my form is:

```
    <form id="PostForm" method="post" action="/view/{{ neighborhood.id }}/posts/" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}

        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.help_text }}
            {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view doesnt return response if form is not valid. To fixt it rewrite view like this:

```
def posts(request, id=None):
    neighborhood = get_object_or_404(Neighborhood, id=id)
    form = PostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = Post(image = request.FILES['image'])
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post = post.save()
            next = request.POST.get('next', '/')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
    else:
        form = PostForm()  
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')          
    return render(request, 'posts.html', context = {'form':form, 'posts':posts, 'neighborhood':neighborhood})
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much. You have no idea how long I spent on that.
On another note, do you have any idea, why the image field is not optional?

Comment: @FANCY_HOOMAN you are welcome! Try to set required=False in form: `image = forms.FileField(label='Select an image file', 
    help_text='Please select a photo to upload', required=False)`

Comment: That ends up giving me a MultiValueDictKeyError : (